# How to package Debian's python3-ebooklib for Fedora

Tags: fedora, python, rpm

It seems this package for ebooks
https://packages.debian.org/buster/python3-ebooklib 
is not (yet) packaged for Fedora.

How to package this into rpm (locally) or make it available in copr?

Comment: as per https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/pathon-lib-for-ebooks/5815, "The project is currently not packaged for Fedora".

Comment: There is an example (package.rpm?) here http://www.last-bastion.net/LBN/up2date/plope/19/item456022870 ... but no SRPM was found.

Answer (score 1):

```
pyp2rpm -o fedora  --srpm -p3 ebooklib
```

will produce an SRPM, which you can the build using Mock.

[Copr](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/) can automate this for you. See https://docs.pagure.org/copr.copr/user_documentation.html#pypi

New build -> Select the source type -> PyPI -> file in the name -> Build

Answer (score 1):

You can install  the latest [`EbookLib`](https://pypi.org/project/EbookLib/) version through `pip`:

```
python3 -m pip install Ebooklib
```